# using std::initializer_list as a member variable

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class `A` that takes an `initializer_list` and stores it as a member variable.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(std::initializer_list<std::string> il) :
        m_il(il)
    {}

    std::initializer_list<std::string> m_il;
};
```

Another class `B` has `A` as a member variable that is default initialized using the `initializer_list`

```
class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        std::cout << *m_a.m_il.begin() << std::endl;
    }

    A m_a { "hello", "bye" };
};
```

Now when I run this code in main, it prints nothing.

```
int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

Why did the code above not print `hello`? Is my usage of `std::initializer_list` incorrect?

Comment: Don't use `initializer_list` as a data member.

Comment: Initializing a non-static class member is even mentioned [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) as something that specifically _doesn't_ extend the lifetime of the underlying temporary

Comment: @DavidG unless "static const / static constexpr" data member.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Copying a `std::initializer_list` does not copy its underlying objects. It's not meant to be used as a container. What you should be doing instead is storing it in something else, like a `std::vector`:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(std::initializer_list<std::string> il) :
        m_il(il)
    {}

    std::vector<std::string> m_il;
};
```