Catching dangerous use of std::initializer_list
#include <initializer_list>

int main() {
    std::initializer_list<int> il = std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3};
    return 0;
}

As I understood it you should not copy std::initilizer_list objects since it's just a a lightweight proxy object. See for example this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48046201/11722
And in Clang 15.0.0 I see this warning:

warning: array backing local initializer list 'il' will be destroyed
at the end of the full-expression [-Wdangling]

However newer clang (or gcc) does not seem to warn about this. (See https://godbolt.org/z/hPfKTP7vo)
-fsanitise=address is also catching the issue in clang 15 if I try to reference the content, but not in newer clang versions. Has the underlying implementation changed?
Why isn't copying it forbidden if it's not safe?

Might be related to guaranteed copy elision?

std::initializer_list belongs in function parameters. There is almost no other case where it should be used. Writing std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3} explicitly or declaring a local variable of the type is already suspect.

Indeed, I was interested in how I could detect things like that sneaking into the code base using compiler warnings, static analysis or sanitizers.

What you are seeing is the different default version of the C++ standard being used, and the difference between those versions.  Clang 15 uses C++14 as the default standard.  That means
std::initializer_list<int> il = std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3};

will make a copy and thus you get the appropriate warning
Clang 16 and above default to C++17 which introduces guaranteed copy elision.  That means
std::initializer_list<int> il = std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3};

becomes
std::initializer_list<int> il{1, 2, 3};

and no copy happens, you just have direct initialization.

Thanks, that makes sense. I do not see the same in gcc though, both the sanitizer and compiler seem happy with the code regardless of the standard passed.

@Zitrax Interesting.  that seems like a bug to me.  Let me see if I can't find anything.

Demo https://godbolt.org/z/39KxojTnq

@Zitrax Doing a litle more testing with GCC on compiler explorer and it looks like GCC is just optimizing away the copy.  If I tell it not to elide then it calls a move constructor (which it shouldn't have): https://godbolt.org/z/GEP6cx98b

The copy can be elided before C++17 as well and then the lifetime of the backing array will be the same as in C++17. That is up to the compiler.

@NathanOliver std::initializer_list has an implicit move constructor that does exactly the same as the copy constructor.
